# Как и можно ли создать переменную в базе данных?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Нужен не повторяющийся id, решил создать переменную в БД mysql, но увы, не нашёл как

Comment: Для получения не повторяющихся id обычно используются поля с атрибутом auto_increment. А переменных в БД не бывает (бывают в запросах на получение данных, но это совсем другая история)

Comment: Переменные в MySQL существуют (и даже четырёх разных типов) - но те, что доступны пользователю для создания и изменения, являются динамическими и несохраняемыми.

Comment: *Нужен не повторяющийся id* С какой целью, для какого именно использования?

Comment: @Akina для регистрации

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/example-AUTO_INCREMENT.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Используй атрибут auto_increment.